# Windws phone 8:Fast resume is not working in my application

Tags: c#, windows-phone, manifest

I am writing application windows phone 8.

I read MSDN artical

[ast app resume for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735579%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Resumeandrefreshthepageonthetopofthebackstack)

i add the ActivationPolicy attribute to the DefaultTask element in WMAppManifest.xml and set the value to “Resume”. But its not working.

**My Case is**:
First time i click on my application Tile-->LoginPage---> second page(Home Page)-->Now press windows button (application goes in backgroung)-->Now click on tile icon and again login page occure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution we have to also change in App.xaml file like **RootFrame_Navigating** Evnt,Application_Activated,Application_Deactivated,etc....

you can fine demo here [Fast app resume backstack sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Fast-app-resume-backstack-f16baaa6)

**Note:** Please check App.xaml file and make changes like demo, And add ActivationPolicy=true; In WMAppManifest.xml file

THanks